# Search bar with NSPredicate doesn't work

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, nspredicate

I've made a view for editing friend, with a searchbar. My adding/deleting friends is working fine, but I've a problem with my adding/deleting friends WITH SEARCHBAR...
My searchbar finds well the email I'm tapping, but the order change :
if I find 2 email with my searchbar, the 2 email will are the 2 first email in my property "Allfriend", and not the email I found with searchbar...
Is there any code to complete in didSelectRowAtIndexPath after NSLog ?

I let you see my code, tell me if you see a problem :

editfriend.h :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface EditFriendsViewController : UITableViewController <UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate>


@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *allUsers;
@property (nonatomic, strong) PFUser *currentUser;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *friends;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *searchResults;
@property (nonatomic, strong) PFUser *user;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *filteredArray;


@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *MindleNav;



-(BOOL)isFriend:(PFUser*)user;

@end
```

editfriend.m :

```
#import "EditFriendsViewController.h"

@interface EditFriendsViewController ()

@end

@implementation EditFriendsViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:self.MindleNav];

    self.searchResults = [[NSArray alloc] init];


    PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
    [query orderByAscending:@"email"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
        else {
            self.allUsers = objects;
            //            self.user = [objects objectAtIndex:0];
            [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
        }
    }];

    self.currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        return [self.searchResults count];
    }
    else
    {
        return [self.allUsers count];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


    PFUser *user = [self.allUsers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [[self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] email];
    } else {
        cell.textLabel.text = user.email;
    }


    if ([self isFriend:user]) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    return cell;
}


#pragma mark - Table view delegate
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    PFRelation *friendsRelation = [self.currentUser relationforKey:@"friendsRelation"];
    PFUser *user = [self.allUsers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        NSLog(@"CLICK search");
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"CLICK");
    }

    if ([self isFriend:user]) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

        for(PFUser *friend in self.friends) {
            if ([friend.objectId isEqualToString:user.objectId]) {
                [self.friends removeObject:friend];
                break;
            }
        }

        [friendsRelation removeObject:user];
    }
    else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        [self.friends addObject:user];
        [friendsRelation addObject:user];
    }

    [self.currentUser saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];
}

#pragma mark - Helper methods
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"email beginswith[c] %@", searchText];
    self.searchResults = [self.allUsers filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                               scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                      objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                     selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
}


- (BOOL)isFriend:(PFUser *)user {
    for(PFUser *friend in self.friends) {
        if ([friend.objectId isEqualToString:user.objectId]) {
            return YES;
        }
    }

    return NO;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array (probably) contains `PFUser` objects and the predicate is:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@", searchText]
```

BEGINSWITH works only for strings and you try to apply it to `PFUser` objects. This is a reason of the crash. If you want to search for users whose names begin with the `searchText`, change the predicate to:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"username beginswith[c] %@", searchText]
```

Comment: Mhhh exactly ! but [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"username beginswith[c] %@", searchText] doesn't work too :(

Comment: I've try : [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"contains[c] %@",searchText]; That's ok for the predicate, but my app crash when I find user... :(

Comment: Can you give more details about the crash?

Comment: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PFUser copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10b46b3a0'"

Comment: and my NSLog for predicate when I tap email@email.com is : email CONTAINS[c] "email@email.com"

Comment: Change  `cell.textLabel.text = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` to `cell.textLabel.text = [[self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] email];`

Comment: that works, when I search email@email.com that find him, but when I click on him, that concern another email... :(

Comment: that always concern the first email (when I tap that add friend, and it's always the same person who is added)... :/ But when I search, the concerned email is display...

Comment: My searchbar finds well the email I'm tapping, but the order change : if I find 2 email with my searchbar, the 2 email will are the 2 first email in my property "Allfriend", and not the email I found with searchbar... Is there any code to complete in didSelectRowAtIndexPath