# Can't do a substring operation with something that isn't a string

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a database with core data and i am trying to make it searchable. It doesn't work and returns this error:

> 'Can't do a substring operation with something that isn't a string 
>   (lhs =  (entity: Device; id: 0x8c63bc0
>    ; data:
>   {.......}

So that is my code for creating cells.

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    self.searchResults = [[NSArray alloc]init];

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // Fetch the devices from persistent data store
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Device"];
    self.devices = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return [self.searchResults count];
    }

    else
    {
        return [self.devices count];

    }

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
  //  return self.devices.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {

        NSManagedObject *device = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [device valueForKey:@"text1"]]];
        [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[device valueForKey:@"text3"]];

    }

    else

    {

    // Configure the cell...
    NSManagedObject *device = [self.devices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [device valueForKey:@"text1"]]];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[device valueForKey:@"text3"]];

    }

    return cell;
}


- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete object from database
        [context deleteObject:[self.devices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Can't Delete! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
            return;
        }

        // Remove device from table view
        [self.devices removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}



#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     */
}


#pragma mark - Segue

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"UpdateJob"]) {
        NSManagedObject *selectedDevice = [self.devices objectAtIndex:[[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row]];
        JobDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.device = selectedDevice;
    }
}
```

and the code for the query:

```
#pragma Search Methods

-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString *)searchText scope:(NSString *)scope

{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@",searchText];
    self.searchResults = [self.devices filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];



}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];
    return YES;
}
```

but it keeps breaking when i enter the first letter. What can i do?

Comment: You might want to see which line of code it is having a problem with.

Comment: doesn't say unfortunately...

Comment: Use breakpoints to track where the problem happens

Comment: this line is  breaking...     `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Search bar with NSPredicate doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24656181/search-bar-with-nspredicate-doesnt-work)

Comment: Have you registered the tableview cell class ? i.e [tableView registerClass:withReuseIdentifier]; ?

Comment: no, how do you do that?

Comment: You only need to register the class if you are not using a storyboard/xib for the cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it. I've added this line of code.

```
if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        // More initializations if needed.
    }
```

just below

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Thanks for all the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

Not a predicate expert but shouldnt `SELF beginswith[c] %@` be `text1 beginswith[c] %@` since the predicate is used on an array of object Device